# Starting same acticity in android studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an app in android studio and I have a java file name Login.java. In which I had checked a particular mpin entered by user exists in firebase real time database or not.

Now I want that in else loop mpin doesn't exists then it should remain on Login activity.

How can this be done?

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

String enteredmPINString;
EditText enteredmPin;
DatabaseReference rootref;

String contactfromPhoneLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    Button mLoginSubmit;
    mLoginSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginSubmit);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b!=null){
        contactfromPhoneLogin = b.getString("contacttoLogin");
        Log.d("abcd",contactfromPhoneLogin);
    }

    rootref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Employees").child(contactfromPhoneLogin).child("empmpin");

    Log.d("abcd","Database reference reached");

  //  enteredmPin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextmPIN);
   // enteredmPINString = enteredmPin.getText().toString();


    View.OnClickListener submitListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            enteredmPin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextmPIN);
            enteredmPINString = enteredmPin.getText().toString();
            Log.d("abcd",enteredmPINString);
            final Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Login.this,NavigationDrawer.class);
            loginIntent.putExtra ("mPINtoNavigation",enteredmPINString);
            Log.d("abcd","Login.java sending"+enteredmPINString);
            startActivity(loginIntent);


            rootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("abcd","onDatachange reached");
                    Log.d("abcd",enteredmPINString);
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(enteredmPINString).exists()){
                        Log.d("abcd","mpin exists");
                        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Login.this,NavigationDrawer.class);
                        loginIntent.putExtra ("mPINtoNavigation",enteredmPINString);
                        Log.d("abcd","Login.java sending"+enteredmPINString);
                        startActivity(loginIntent);
                    }
                    else{

                        Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Invalid mPIN!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    };
    mLoginSubmit.setOnClickListener(submitListener);
}

public void erp_site(View view){
    Intent erpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://web.nbccho.com/erp/"));
    startActivity(erpIntent);
}

public void nbcc_site(View view){
    Intent nbcc_siteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.nbccindia.com/nbccindia/index.jsp"));
    startActivity(nbcc_siteIntent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the intent in onClick();

```
    View.OnClickListener submitListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        enteredmPin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextmPIN);
        enteredmPINString = enteredmPin.getText().toString();
        Log.d("abcd",enteredmPINString);
        Log.d("abcd","Login.java sending"+enteredmPINString);
```